# Kotlin / Android Studio - Beginner

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I had hard case to understand how it works, basically i cannot write code which text from form will be save in variable and after it printed... I saw video on youtube, tons of faq blogs but they are using fully java and code in wrong or old formulas....

I have:

activityPlay.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/imie"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="182dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="281dp" />



<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="115dp"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="216dp" />
```

and

MainActivity.kt

```
val submit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submit)

val imie = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.imie)
submit.setOnClickListener {
        val userText = imie.text.toString()

    }
```

May you help me and clearly fix the code for save text to value... ?

Comment: Hello, what the error you have got?  What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you managed to save the data into a variable. But you don't use it afterward.

Change

```
submit.setOnClickListener {
        val userText = imie.text.toString()

    }
```

to

```
submit.setOnClickListener {
        val userText = imie.text.toString()
        submit.text = userText
    }
```

This will change the text on the btn